# Al cambiar mi tabla a una tabla dinámica, el textarea de mi ventana modal se agranda sin hacer caso a los estilos

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Al principio los anchos se modificaron sin hacer caso de los estilos, eso pude arreglarlo poniendo la ventana modal en un `<table>` y el header y el article se veía un hueco entre ellos que lo arreglé con un margin-bottom negativo (que no me gusta ponerlos en negativa, no lo he probado pero a lo mejor al aumentar o disminuir la pantalla o ponerlo en otra plataforma seguramente se descuadre).

Pero **el `<textarea>` de primeras se bien, pero donde está el ajustar el tamaño del textarea lo tocas y se agranda el alto un montón** (sin que puedas disminuir el alto solo aumentarlo más) **no hace caso de los estilos pese a tener un max-height !important.** Y no entiendo por qué pasa, ni sé arreglarlo (pero en el inspector del navegador puedo fijarlo, pero si hago ese cambio en el fichero de mi proyecto no hace caso).

```
<style>
/*estilos para la tabla*/
table th{background:chocolate;color:white;}

td{max-width:400px;}

.scroll{word-break: break-word;max-height:60px;overflow:auto;}
button{cursor:pointer;}

/*ventana modal*/
header{background: chartreuse;}
#show-modal:hover{cursor:pointer;}
.modal{position:fixed;top:-100vh;left:0;z-index:99999999;width:100vw;height:100vh;opacity:0;transition:opacity 0.35s ease;}
.modal .content-modal{width:100%;max-width:500px;position:fixed;left:50%;top:-100vh;transition:top 0.35s ease;margin-left:-250px;z-index:9999999;}
.modal h2{padding:0.5em;text-align:center;color:#444444;margin:0;}
.modal article{margin-top:-17px;}
.close-modal{color:red;position:absolute;top:0.2em;right:0.375em;padding:5px;font-weight:bold;font-size:1.5em;text-decoration:none;}
.modal:target{opacity:1;top:0;}
.modal:target .content-modal{top:50px;transition:top 0.35s ease;}
@media (max-width: 500px){
    .modal .content-modal{width:90%;max-width:none;left:5%;margin-left:0;}  
}
/*fin*/
</style>
  <!--VENTANA MODAL-->
<table>
<aside id="modal" class="modal">
    <div class="content-modal">
        <header>
            <a href="#" class="close-modal">X</a>
            <h2>Añade o modifique el comentario:</h2>
        </header>
        <article>
            <form action="/tablapruebas.php" method="post" multipart="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <textarea id="COMENTARIOS" name="COMENTARIOS" rows="10" style="min-width:100%;max-width:100%;max-height:93%;min-height:93%;height:164px !important;" required></textarea><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Añadir" style="width:100%;text-align:center;cursor:pointer;">
                
                </input>
            </form>
        </article>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="btn-close-model"></a>
</aside></table>
<!--FIN V.M-->
<?php

if ($resultado->num_rows > 0) {
    ?>
<table id="tabla" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Personas</th>
            <th>Descripción</th>
            <th>Fecha evento</th>
            <th>Fecha creación</th>
            <th>Lugar</th>
            <th>Contacto</th>
            <th>Ruta archivos</th>
            <th>Comentarios</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <?php
    while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
      
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="scroll"><?php echo $row["personas"] ?></div></td>
            <td><div class="scroll"><?php echo $row["DESCRIPCION"] ?></div></td>
            <td><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row["FECHA"])) ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["CREATED"] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["LUGAR"] ?></td>
            <td><div class="scroll"><?php echo $row["CONTACTO"] ?></div></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["RUTA_ARCHIVO"] ?></td>
            <td><div class="scroll"><?php echo $row["COMENTARIOS"] ?>
            <a href="#modal" id="show-modal"><button style="width:15px;"><img src="images/modificar.png" style="width:15px;height:15px;"></button></a>
        </div></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>               
 </table>  
  <?php
} else {
  echo "No hay resultados";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

**Al principio pensaba que podría ser por los estilos y scripts de jquery pero los comenté y daba el mismo fallo.**

Gracias,
Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lo que quieres conseguir no puedes usar medidas relativas como el **%** si no que tienes que irte a medidas absolutas. Usando píxeles podrías restringir el `<textarea>` para que tenga una altura mínima de 164px y una máxima de 200px, por ejemplo.

Tuve que quitar el **PHP** de tu código para poder mostrarlo en el ejecutable y se ha de visualizar en "Ventana completa" para apreciar la solución.

```css
/*estilos para la tabla*/
table th{background:chocolate;color:white;}

td{max-width:400px;}

.scroll{word-break: break-word;max-height:60px;overflow:auto;}
button{cursor:pointer;}

/*ventana modal*/
header{background: chartreuse;}
#show-modal:hover{cursor:pointer;}
.modal{position:fixed;top:-100vh;left:0;z-index:99999999;width:100vw;height:100vh;opacity:0;transition:opacity 0.35s ease;}
.modal .content-modal{width:100%;max-width:500px;position:fixed;left:50%;top:-100vh;transition:top 0.35s ease;margin-left:-250px;z-index:9999999;}
.modal h2{padding:0.5em;text-align:center;color:#444444;margin:0;}
.modal article{margin-top:-17px;}
.close-modal{color:red;position:absolute;top:0.2em;right:0.375em;padding:5px;font-weight:bold;font-size:1.5em;text-decoration:none;}
.modal:target{opacity:1;top:0;}
.modal:target .content-modal{top:50px;transition:top 0.35s ease;}
@media (max-width: 500px){
    .modal .content-modal{width:90%;max-width:none;left:5%;margin-left:0;}  
}
/*fin*/
```

```html
<!--VENTANA MODAL-->
<table>
<aside id="modal" class="modal">
    <div class="content-modal">
        <header>
            <a href="#" class="close-modal">X</a>
            <h2>Añade o modifique el comentario:</h2>
        </header>
        <article>
            <form action="/tablapruebas.php" method="post" multipart="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <textarea id="COMENTARIOS" name="COMENTARIOS" rows="10" style="min-width:100%;max-width:100%;max-height:200px;min-height:164px;height:164px !important;" required></textarea><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Añadir" style="width:100%;text-align:center;cursor:pointer;">
                
                </input>
            </form>
        </article>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="btn-close-model"></a>
</aside></table>
<!--FIN V.M-->

<table id="tabla" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Personas</th>
            <th>Descripción</th>
            <th>Fecha evento</th>
            <th>Fecha creación</th>
            <th>Lugar</th>
            <th>Contacto</th>
            <th>Ruta archivos</th>
            <th>Comentarios</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td><div class="scroll">Personas</div></td>
          <td><div class="scroll">Descripción</div></td>
          <td>Fecha</td>
          <td>Creado</td>
          <td>Lugar</td>
          <td><div class="scroll">Contacto</div></td>
          <td>Ruta archivo</td>
          <td><div class="scroll">Comentarios
          <a href="#modal" id="show-modal"><button style="width:15px;"><img src="images/modificar.png" style="width:15px;height:15px;"></button></a>
      </div></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>               
 </table>
```

Comment: Juraría que eso lo había probado. 
Funciona, muchas gracias